# Can't connect Apple TV to iTunes after installing a new router

Tags: macos, itunes, home-networking, appletv

I replaced an old router with a Linksys WRT610N. Everything works great, except I can no longer connect iTunes 9 on my Mac (running 10.6) to the Apple TV since installing the new router (the old router was a Linksys as well with nothing special configured).

I can ping the Apple TV by IP address and ssh into it. The Apple TV can get onto the internet fine and can also connect fine to my NAS (via smb). I've gone through the standard connect process and after typing the PIN into iTunes, iTunes says it's unable to connect, though it seems to be able to briefly see the Apple TV, since it is listed under devices with a "setup this device" next to it.

My firewall is disabled on the Mac and there isn't anything special about the router.

One thing I find odd -- since upgrading the router, I can no longer just ping "appletv.local" from the Mac -- the name doesn't exist. Is it possible the router is blocking some ports on my local machines?

Comment: I was able to telnet to the IP of the appletv on port 3689 (the itunes music sharing port), so it looks like the firewall of the router isn't blocking anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whew!  got it.  thanks to this person,

https://davejamesmiller.wordpress.com/2008/01/01/airport-express-itunes-sharing-bonjour-linksys-router/

I had to enable "Multicast Filtering" in my router.  Not having that checked interferes with Bonjour (which is what itunes/appletv sharing uses).

Multicast fitlering is:

"Multicasting allows for multiple transmissions to specific recipients at the same time. If multicasting is permitted, then the Router will allow IP multicast packets to be forwarded to the appropriate computers."

after reading that definition, it seems like I should NOT be filtering multicast, but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a router as well as a switch, try connecting both the computer & appleTV to the same device (router or switch). It SHOULD work if one's on the router and one's on the switch, but in practice I find that it sometimes doesn't.

Comment: I'm using an all in one device (router/wifi/switch/etc)... the mac is on wifi, but the appletv is plugged in to one of the ethernet ports.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off IPv6 seemed to fix it for me.

I have been having the same problems:

- iTunes(mac) wired --> switch/wifi bridge --> Netgear wireless router --> ATV2 (wireless) = fails
- iTunes(man) wireless --> Netgear wireless router --> ATV2 (wireless) = works

Note, in both cases, it shows up in iTunes, just cannot connect.

I found this [Itunes 10 won't connect to Apple TV with Airplay](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2598887&start=0&tstart=0) and it now works w/o a problem.

Btw, I couldn't figure out how to change the settings to enable multicast.

Other things that people seemed to say were issues were p